Is it possible to have a streamlit app launch a browser on start up using a docker container?
Without a docker container, one can execute streamlit run app.py in the terminal and streamlit will automatically open a browser tab with the app, however, I find this is not the case when streamlit is in a container. I have followed the instructions on this webpage, but the user must manually browse to http://0.0.0.0:8501 or http://localhost:8501.
Here is what my Dockerfile looks like
FROM python:3.10-slim
LABEL maintainer="Steven Herrera stevenherrera46375@utexas.edu"

WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl
RUN mkdir /app/.streamlit && mkdir /app/resources

COPY ./docker_requirements.txt /app/docker_requirements.txt
COPY ./.streamlit/config.toml /app/.streamlit/config.toml
COPY ./resources/video_library_favicon.png /app/resources/video_library_favicon.png

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pip==23.3.1 && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/docker_requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8501/_stcore/health

COPY app.py /app/app.py
# streamlit will say you can view the app at http://0.0.0.0:8501 
# but you actually need to use 127.0.0.1:8501 or localhost:8501 in your browser
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]

Here is the command I use to build the image:
docker build -t youtube-comment-microservice .

Here is the command I use to run the container:
docker run -p 8501:8501 youtube-comment-microservice

If you would like to see the entire project, feel free to look at my GitHub repo under the dev branch.

A container runs in an isolated environment and doesn't normally have access to the end user's desktop.  Docker open a url in the host browser has a couple of suggestions, but for the most part, you can't.  (Use localhost in the URL, 0.0.0.0 – "all interfaces" – doesn't make sense there.)

Ah, I feared as much. Thank you!
